# Error al intentar agregar referencia del WebService WCF en xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, wcf

Hola estoy haciendo una app en xamarin.forms y estoy intentando conectarla al webservice que cree pero cuando quiero agregar la referencia me figura el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya les agradecería su respuesta.

Comment: buenas, mira esto https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2890 a ver si te ayuda